# Instantiated object use to display stored information in another class

Tags: java, oop, instantiation

I instantiated a class so that the information that I will input is stored into it. But I having difficulty in displaying the information that is stored. When I compiled it will say that I havent initialized the variable.

```
    public class REPORTS
{
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x=choices();

         STUDENT stud;
         EQUIPMENT equip;
         RESERVATION reserve;
        switch(x)
        {
            case 1:
            { 
              // Code here for input

               stud = new STUDENT(Studid,Studname,Studcourse,Studlevel);

               break;
            }
            case 2:
            { 
               // Code also here for input
               equip = new EQUIPMENT(eqpmntid,qty,eqpmntname);
               break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
               // Same goes for here input
               reserve = new RESERVATION(studentid,equipid1,reservationdate,returndate);
               break;
            }
           case 4:
            {

               stud.display(); // error here variable might not have been initialized
               break;
            }      
           case 5:
            {

               equip.display(); // same goes here
               break;
            }
         case 6:
            {
               reserve.display(); // and also here
               break;           
            }
        }
```

Here is the detailed error message:

[image: This is the error]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to change your program behavior; There is one possible syntactic way of casting a new Object to Student at beginning of your code but you will probably get a runtime error. To change the behavior you can initialize objects with arguments that are null or empty or dummy objects based on the arguments that your constructor get and then Set the fields to appropriate values in related switch case; For example your first lines should look like this:

```java
Student stud = new Student("", Null, dummyObject);
```

Comment: it will cause a runtime error.  says it cannot converterted or cant cast the class object into the Student